# Binding Label's Text to a Variable in Xamarin forms c#

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, binding, inotifypropertychanged

So Im trying to creat a simple app like a shopping app. so I have categories and multiple items for each category, and when you get to choose an item then you will have the posibility to increase how many you need or delete the item. For exemple I chosed three items, so my cart have 3 items where each one have an Add button and a delete button. When I hit the add button the number of the items shown should increase and so on.

so what I've done so far is creating a JSON file that having all my categories, and once I hit a category I get to deserialize another JSON file that have all my items, so the items shown depends on the category I chosed of course.

Now each time i choose an item it get added to the cart and shown on the bottom page with a + and - buttons and so on.

so I created a category class to deserialize my json, and an objets class to deserialize my Item's json. I implememted the INotifyChangedProperty in the objets class so that I can keep showin whenever the number of a chosen item get increased, so basicly thats my ViewModel, but I guess that it's like that I need a ViewModel of each created item ? so I guess what I really need to use is the ObservableCollection ..

I hope I explained everything well, and waiting for your feedbacks about if Im doing it right or wrong and how should i proceed to get what I want. thank you so much

Comment: This is well documented - have you read the docs on binding?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data-binding-basics

Comment: @Shahid,If you want to bind the variable to Label.Text, when variable is changed, the Label.Text will change, you need to implement **INotifyPropertychanged** interface. You can take a look:https://xamarinhelp.com/xamarin-forms-binding/

Comment: @shahid Are you using Xaml or .CS coding for designing? Shall I provide with xaml? But it is the very basic thing for Xamarin you can cross check with documentation.

Comment: @Jason I want to do it with C#, couldn't find something that works for me. and Yes i did

Comment: @CherryBu-MSFT that is exact I will try to imlement it with the exemple you provide me and give you a feed back. thank you so much

Comment: @KiShOrE I already know how to do it in the XAML, right now Im doing it in the .CS, I just need to use the **INotifyPropertychanged** but I was looking here for an exemple of how to use it correctly 
Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the problems is that to set the bindingcontext to my "Objets" Class I have to put the arguments in it, and then my Label well get a precised value ... what should I do ?

I have written a sample for your model, you can take a look:

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout>
        <Label x:Name="label1" />

        <Button
            x:Name="btn1"
            Clicked="Btn1_Clicked"
            Text="change value" />
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>


public partial class Page15 : ContentPage
{
    public Objets model { get; set; }
    public Page15()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        model= new Objets("test 1", 1.001f, " test11111", 12);
        this.BindingContext = model;
        label1.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "nbr_objet");
    }

    private void Btn1_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        model.nbr_objet = 20;
    }
}
public class Objets : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string Designation { get; set; }
    public float Prix { get; set; }
    public string imageUrl { get; set; }
    private int Nbr_Objet;

    public int nbr_objet
    {
        get { return Nbr_Objet; }
        set
        {
            Nbr_Objet = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("nbr_objet");
        }
    }

   

    public Objets(string Designation, float Prix, string imageUrl, int Nbr_Objet)
    {
        this.Designation = Designation;
        this.Prix = Prix;
        this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
        this.Nbr_Objet = Nbr_Objet;
    }
    
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

   
    public void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

**Update:**

> but I guess that it's like that I need a ViewModel of each created item ? so I guess what I really need to use is the ObservableCollection ..

You said that you have three categories, and each category have many items, If you display these in ListView, category is used as Group header, and I suggest you can use the same model for different item for different categories, then add in Observablecollection, because it have implemented INotifyPropertyChanged interface.

About ListView group, you can take a look:

https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/master/UserInterface/ListView/Grouping

If you still have another question, I suggest you can create new thread to ask, because this thread is very long.

Comment: thank you so much, that made me see things clearer. I will edit my question again so that you guys can see what Im trying to do, maybe Im doing it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

to set a binding programatically

```
// set the BindingContext for the page
this.BindingContext = new MyViewModel();

// Title is a public property on MyViewModel
myLabel.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "Title");
```

in order for the UI to update when the VM is changed, the VM needs to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`

Comment: I implemented the INotifyPropertyChanged in the VM correctly as shown here : https://xamarinhelp.com/xamarin-forms-binding/  . And added the binding as well as the binding context but for some reason the app stops responding. I don't even get an Exception

Comment: without seeing your actual code there's no way we can help you debug this

Comment: Okey I managed to get it working, I guess all what I need right now is to set the binding context correctly, the problem is that MyViewModel is a class that has several arguments, but if I precised the arguments values then that exactly what i will get !
This class that Im using is the one Im based on to deserialize my json file ... Can you suggest me any solutions ?

Comment: Again, without seeing your code there is no way for me to help you

Comment: Edit the question

Answer (score 0):

This is some guidance that might help with your problem. Your code is messy and I think that is causing your confusion (you have several things named very similarly).

```
int Nbr_Objet;

public int nbr_objet { get{...} set {...}}

this.Nbr_Objet= Nbr_Objet;
```

this shows me that you are setting your member variable `Nbr_Objet` directly, when you do that the property change notification doesn't fire - you need to assign the value through the public `nbr_objet` for that to happen.

I'd suggest you define the binding in XAML, and make sure you bind to the property `nbr_objet`, not the private member variable (field) `Nbr_Objet`. 
If you want to avoid confusion, follow the C# coding standard and name your member variable `_nbrObjet`, and camel case your property name `public int NbrObjet { get {...`.

Comment: Thank you very much, but the problem that I have is setting up the binding context, How can i set it in the XAML ?

Comment: @ShahidOd can you post what you have so far? You can strip out anything not relevant, but try to include the page/component level XAML, plus the label.

Comment: I will edit my question again so that you guys can see what Im trying to do, maybe Im doing it wrong.